# how to check a multiline field for null

Tags: 2007

I have a custom list in 2007 with columns as Ticket number, Target Violated, violation category, PoR. Now I am populating all the columns except the PoR and PoR is expected to be populated by the respective teams. After this I just want to create a view where PoR is empty to further define the KPI list. This will give me the how much percentage is pending for entering the POR. My problem is I can not filter the view on PoR being a multi line text Further I dont have Designer for 2007 though I have designer 2010. but 2010 has no backward compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the filter condition using multiline text fields. It allows only the opertors "Begins" or "Contains" which doesn't suite for checking null. As you don't have SPD 2007, check if you can deploy a custom code solution where in you can set the filter condition for that view programmatically.